# PHP Xpath: Get node value by class name

Tags: php, xpath

I'm using xpath to pull data out of a piece of HTML code and I've been able to pull out most data except for one piece.

The HTML is structured like below, but there might only be one li or two or all three so I need to be able to target it by classname.

```
<li>
    <a href="http://www.website.com">Product URL</a>
</li>
<li>
    <ul>
        <li class="itemone">1</li>
        <li class="itemtwo">2</li>
        <li class="itemthree">3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This code is already retrieved using an xpath query and then further data is pulled out of the results of the xpath query with the below PHP snippet.

```
$rawData = $xpath->query('//div[@id=\'products\']/ul/li[contains(@class, \'product\')]');

foreach($rawData as $data) {
    $productRaw = $data->getElementsByTagName('li');
    $productTitle = $productRaw[0]->getElementsByTagName('a')[0]->nodeValue;
    $productRefCode = $productRaw[0]->getElementsByTagName('span')[0]->nodeValue;
    $productPrice = $productRaw[1]->getElementsByTagName('li');
}
```

The problem is `$productPrice`, the line above is pulling out the below node list.

```
DOMNodeList Object
(
    [length] => 3
)
```

I'm looking to find anything in the above node list that has a classname of `itemtwo`, I've using an `$xpath->query` on `$productRaw[1]` and also tried `getElementsByClassName` but with no luck, I've tried the two snippets below with no luck.

```
$productPrice = $productRaw[1]->getElementsByTagName('li')->getElementsByClassName('itemtwo');
...
$productPrice = $productRaw[1]->query('//li[contains(@class, \'itemtwo\')]');
```

Both snippets give an error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getElementsByClassName()` and `Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::query()`.

Comment: Please post the entirety of what you have tried.

Comment: @Jon, I've added the two lines I've tried so far.

Comment: I recommend to use [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) php library and parser  html dom simply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

har07's answer was on the right track, but it only returned the node list with length set to 3 like I was already receiving with my existing code.

Original code:

```
$productPrice = $productRaw[1]->getElementsByTagName('li');
```

har07's suggestion:

```
$productPrice = $xpath->query('.//li[contains(@class, "itemtwo")]', $productRaw->item(1));
```

Solution, which returns the node value where an elements class name is equal to `itemtwo`:

```
$productPrice = $xpath->query('.//li[contains(@class, \'itemtwo\')]', $productRaw[1])->item(1)->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `DOMXPath::query`, passing XPath string as the first parameter and `DOMNode` as the second, to execute XPath relative to certain `DOMNode` context, for example :

```
foreach($rawData as $data) {
    $productRaw = $data->getElementsByTagName('li');
    .....
    $productPrice = $xpath->query('.//li[contains(@class, "itemtwo")]', $productRaw->item(1));
}
```

Also use `.` at the beginning of your XPath expression to explicitly tell that the expression is relative to current context node.

Comment: This just gives me the `DOMNodeList Object` with `length` set to 3 like above in my original question.

Comment: That's mean I misunderstood the context of your codes. Which li element, in the posted HTML snippet, that $productRaw[1] references?

Comment: `$productRaw[1]` references the first level `LI` in my html snippet which has the child `UL` with 3 `LI` elements, out of these 3 `LI` elements I'm trying to target one that has a classname of `itemtwo`.

Comment: @llanato the code should work as far as I can see, see the demo: https://eval.in/499654. `$productRaw` references the 2nd outer `li` there, and using the same XPath the code successfully print the value of `<li class="itemtwo">2</li>`. Make you didn't miss the `.` at the beginning of the XPath

Comment: Got it with a slight modification of your solution above, `$productPrice = $xpath->query('.//li[contains(@class, \'itemtwo\')]', $productRaw[1])->item(1)->nodeValue;`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$str = '<li>   
    <a href="http://www.website.com">Product URL</a></li>
    <li>
         <ul>
             <li class="itemone">1</li>
             <li class="itemtwo">2</li>
             <li class="itemthree">3</li>
         </ul>
    </li>';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$productPrices = $xpath->query("//li[@class='itemtwo']");

foreach ($productPrices as $productPrice) {
    print $productPrice->nodeValue."\n";
}
```